# Is there a difference between -x vs x * -1.0f?

Tags: java, floating-point, negate

In java, is there a difference between negating a variable vs multiplying a variable by a float minus one, if the variable is also a float?

Comment: The latter should result in a floating point negative number. As for the first, it depends on the type of `x`.

Comment: Yes, as @npinti pointed out, -x will be integer or double or whatever type x  was and multiplying it with -1.0f will implicitly convert it to float.

Comment: @Vucko: Yes, but he writes that the variable is also float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JLS §15.15.4 "Unary Minus Operator -", we find that

> For floating-point values, negation is not the same as subtraction from zero, because if x is +0.0, then 0.0-x is +0.0, but -x is -0.0. **Unary minus merely inverts the sign of a floating-point number**. Special cases of interest:
>
> If the operand is NaN, the result is NaN. (Recall that NaN has no sign (§4.2.3).)
>
> If the operand is an infinity, the result is the infinity of opposite sign.
>
> If the operand is a zero, the result is the zero of opposite sign.

(Highlight mine)

The difference can be seen in the emitted bytecode. Unary minus is a simple `fneg`, while `(-1f * x)` results in an `fload` and `fmul`, which is likely slightly slower.

I have no idea if the JIT compiler will optimize it.

For readability, using `-x` is usually better.

Comment: Does Java follow IEEE 754-2008? It specifies negation as a bit-level operation affecting NaN : "5.5.1 Sign bit operations. Implementations shall provide the following homogeneous quiet-computational sign bit operations for all supported arithmetic formats; they only affect the sign bit. The operations treat floating-point numbers and NaNs alike, and signal no exception. These operations may propagate non-canonical encodings. [...] negate(x) copies a floating-point operand x to a destination in the same format, reversing the sign bit. negate(x) is not the same as subtraction(0, x) (see 6.3).

Comment: IEEE 754-2008 states further with regard to the sign bit of NaNs:: "6.3 The sign bit. When either an input or result is NaN, this standard does not interpret the sign of a NaN. Note, however, that operations on bit strings — copy, negate, abs, copySign — specify the sign bit of a NaN result, sometimes based upon the sign bit of a NaN operand. The logical predicate totalOrder is also affected by the sign bit of a NaN operand."

Comment: By default, Java takes some liberties and allows higher-precision intermediate results. Using the `strictfp` keyword, Java obeys IEEE 754 - but according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474424/any-ieee754r-compliant-implementations-for-java Java did not adopt the new 754-2008 variant.

Answer (score 2):

Java uses binary floating point representation of IEEE, with the sign represented by a separate bit. Both multiplying by `-1` and inverting the sign with `-x` are done by flipping this sign bit, while keeping the rest of the representation unchanged. That is why there is no difference in the result, because `-1.0f` has an exact representation, and there is no chance of changing the precision of representation of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

If `x` was already a `float` then there is no difference. However the `-x` is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight difference in the bytecode produced:

```
float one(float x) {
  return -x;
}

float two(float x) {
  return x * -1.f;
}

float three(float x) {
  return -1.f * x;
}
```

Decompile to:

```
  float one(float);
    Code:
       0: fload_1
       1: fneg
       2: freturn

  float two(float);
    Code:
       0: fload_1
       1: ldc           #2                  // float -1.0f
       3: fmul
       4: freturn

  float three(float);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // float -1.0f
       2: fload_1
       3: fmul
       4: freturn
```

I would imagine that the `fneg` instruction is slightly faster than the `fload_1/fmul`; but the difference is likely to be negligible (and very possibly optimized out by the JIT).